# Why is inserting same QAction before first element inserts it to the end?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I try to reorder `QMenu` actions. In some situations, I get a bug-like behavior. Let's we have the next code:

```
QMenu menu;
QAction *a1 = menu.addAction("a1");
QAction *a2 = menu.addAction("a2");
QAction *a3 = menu.addAction("a3");
QAction *a4 = menu.addAction("a4");

menu.insertAction(a1, a1);

for(QAction * a: menu.actions()){
    qDebug("%s", qPrintable(a->text()));
}
```

this print:

```
a2
a3
a4
a1
```

Is it correct? I suspected the item "a1" would remain at index [0].

Comment: what is the idea of inserting an action ***Before*** itself ???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add more than one QAction to same QMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847841/how-can-i-add-more-than-one-qaction-to-same-qmenu)

Comment: this is a pseudo-code with bug reproduction. It happens in some situations

Comment: See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#addAction, what you are doing is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the behaviour is correct, here is the source code from insertAction method

```
void QWidget::insertAction(QAction *before, QAction *action)
{
    if (Q_UNLIKELY(!action)) {
        qWarning("QWidget::insertAction: Attempt to insert null action");
        return;
    }
    Q_D(QWidget);
    if(d->actions.contains(action))
        removeAction(action);             //[1]
    int pos = d->actions.indexOf(before);            //[2]
    if (pos < 0) {
        before = 0;
        pos = d->actions.size();              //[3]
    }
    d->actions.insert(pos, action);        //[4]
    QActionPrivate *apriv = action->d_func();
    apriv->widgets.append(this);
    QActionEvent e(QEvent::ActionAdded, action, before);
    QCoreApplication::sendEvent(this, &e);
}
```

the important section is in the lines [1], [2] and [3]

> [1] since a1 is in the list, it will be removed,
>
> [2] since a1 is not in the list, pos is -1
>
> [3] pos is not 3, the size of the list after removing the a1
>
> [4] a1 is inserted at index 3

result:

> a2 a3 a4 a1